# Adding attr to css

Tags: html, css, attr

I have the following html and I am trying to add attr(src) to the css but it does not seem to work

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" width="1500" height="450" data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" data-image-id="2679" class="ut-adaptive-image wp-post-image skip-lazy skip-lazy ut-portfolio-featured-image" data-loaded="true">

.ut-adaptive-image {
background-image: attr (data-src url);
}
```

Comment: Css does not have `.` as concatenation, so your rule is invalid. Do `attr(data-src)`

Answer (score 1):

You will eventually be able to use

```
background-image: attr(data-image-src url);
```

but that is not implemented anywhere yet to my knowledge. In the above, url is an optional "type-or-unit" parameter to attr(). See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#attr-notation.